# Fill ajax success data on another page is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am calling data from `database` and want to fill the data on the controls. So for that, I am using `Ajax` webmethod like below

```
function getAllRecordForCurrentRow(val) {
        debugger;
        var row = val.parentNode.parentNode;            
        var ID = row.cells[7].innerText.trim();

        $.ajax({
            url: "VSATApprover.aspx/GET_DATA_FOR_CURRENT_RECORD_APPROVER",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: ID }),
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (r) {
                //alert(r.d.SAP_ID);
                $('#txtSapId').val([r.d.SAP_ID]);
                $('#txtContactdetails').val([r.d.CONTACT_DETAILS]);
                window.open('VSATUpdateForm.aspx', '_blank');

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Error while selecting list..!!');
            }
        })
    }
```

My issue here is

The value which is under `success` function needs to be filled is on another page and by this way it is not working. So how should I fill the values

Comment: These elements `txtSapId` and `txtContactdetails` are in next page?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: yes they are in next page. what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set these values to some `localStorage` and then on the next page you need to get it from `localStorage` on `document.ready`. Consider below example:

**Page 1 Ajax JS**

```
success: function (r) {
         localStorage.setItem('SapID',r.d.SAP_ID);
         localStorage.setItem('ContactDetails',r.d.CONTACT_DETAILS);
         window.open('VSATUpdateForm.aspx', '_blank');
}
```

Now since you have it in `localStorage` you can write below `js` in next page:

**Page 2 JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //get it from localStorage
   var sapid=localStorage.getItem('SapID'); 
   var contdetails=localStorage.getItem('ContactDetails');

   //set it to textboxes
   $('#txtSapId').val(sapid);
   $('#txtContactdetails').val(contdetails);
});
```

That's it.

Comment: yes, I am also trying like this little bit same, check this `sessionStorage.setItem('SITE_ID', r.d.SITE_ID);` and on control page like this `if (sessionStorage.getItem('SITE_ID')) {
                $("#txtSiteId").val(sessionStorage.getItem('SITE_ID'));
            }` is that fine ?

Comment: Yea.. that's fine too.. But if you want to persist data across system restarts or browser close, then sessionStorage wouldn't help am afraid..

Comment: i appreciate urs effort too. +1 and accepting ur answer :) thanks Man..!

Comment: Yes.. definitely.. But see to it that if you really have a requirement of persisting data upon long time.. Dig more on `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` is what I would suggest.. :)

Comment: yes, I need that data for long time. coz there are 50 fields which user might edit based upon his requirement. So i guess i need to change with your code for future prospect.

Comment: Well.. Yea.. But without detailed specification, like, what actually application is doing, I am afraid that I wouldn't be able to given to precise solution here..

Comment: hey are u thier ? just one small suggestion ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146531/discussion-between-vvvv-and-guruprasad-rao).